# How to run a command before browsersync to reload

Tags: javascript, browserify, browser-sync

I'm using browser-sync to reload my page after some change. But now I need to run browserify before the page reload.

I'm using this command to start server:
`browser-sync start --server --files "*.js"`

And I'm using this command do build a file:
`browserify main.js -o bundle.js`

Is there something like this:
`browser-sync start --server --files "*.js" --before-reload "browserify main.js -o bundle.js"` ???

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to this problem with Gulp. First install the dependencies:

```
npm i --save-dev browser-sync browserify gulp gulp-cli vinyl-source-stream
```

Then I created the gulp file: gulpfile.js

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var browserify  = require('browserify');
var source      = require('vinyl-source-stream');

gulp.task('browserify', function() {
    return browserify('main.js')
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
});


gulp.task('browsersync-reload', ['browserify'], function (done) {
    browserSync.reload();
    done();
});


gulp.task('default', ['browserify'], function () {

    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "."
        }
    });

    gulp.watch("*.js", ['browsersync-reload']);
});
```

So I use gulp's command to start browsersync:

```
./node_modules/.bin/gulp
```

Reference: https://github.com/ailtonbsj/es5-oo